# Regular Expression For Not Allowed Dash(-)

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need expression for accept any characters but no dash(-)
I used this format but not worked for me

```
^[^-]*$
```

Comment: How are you checking that match (regex in .net code, regexvalidator, ..)? Do you have an example where the match failed? Could you explain "not worked for me"?

Comment: it works ... see http://regex101.com/r/nB2lL9/5